# ActionScript - BeginBitmapFill With BitmapData Library Asset?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, assets

I've imported an image asset (Background.jpg) to my Flash CS5 library and exported it to ActionScript as class Bitmap with a base type of BitmapData.

the following code returns the following error:

```
backgroundTexture = new Shape();
backgroundTexture.graphics.beginBitmapFill(Background);
backgroundTexture.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
backgroundTexture.graphics.endFill();
```

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of
>   type Class to an unrelated type
>   flash.display:BitmapData.

[image]

so what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an instance of the `Background` BitmapData object:

```
backgroundTexture.graphics.beginBitmapFill(new Background());
```

`Background` is a reference to the class. `new Background()` creates an instance of the class.

Comment: wow, i can't believe i didn't realize that... how embarrassing.  thanks zzzBov.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978, it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

I have more experience with Flex than Flash, so I don't know the UI details, but I believe what you want is:

```
var background:BitmapAsset = new Background() as BitmapAsset;
backgroundTexture.graphics.beginBitmapFill(background.bitmapData);
```

This is assuming that your UI generates the following ActionScript or its equivalent:

```
[Embed(source="Background.jpg")]
public var Background:Class;
```

See:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/loading_images_library_as3.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html